# Why Jquery Datatable initComplete/onInit events are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatable in my code. I am loading the data via an ajax request. For each row created in my table there is one button called delete. The on-click event of this button reads an attribute called "r_id" and then applies a soft-deletion in my database. My code is like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var parity = 3;
var tr = "";
$.ajax({
        url: "https://" + window.myLocalVar + "/api/rewards/findAllRewardsByStatusID/" + parity,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (rewards) {
            if (rewards.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rewards.length; i++) {
                    var reward = rewards[i].Reward;
                    var reward_price = "$ " + rewards[i].Price;
                    var r_id = rewards[i].RewardID;
                    tr += '<tr r_id="' + r_id + '">\
                        <td>' + reward + '</td>\
                        <td>' + reward_price + '</td>\
                        <td>\
                            <button r_id="' + r_id + '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">delete</button>\
                        </td>\
                    </tr>';
                    if (i % 10 == 0 || i == rewards.length - 1) {
                        $("#submitted_rewards > tbody").append(tr);
                        tr = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            $('#submitted_rewards').on('init.dt', function () {
                // click event for each tr
                $("#submitted_rewards tbody tr td:not(:last-child)").on("click", function () {
                    var r_id = $(this).parent().attr("r_id");
                    window.location.href = "./reward-info.aspx?id=" + r_id;
                });

                $(".delete").click(function () {
                    var r = $(this).attr("r_id");
                    $("tr[r_id=" + r + "]").fadeOut();
                });
            }).DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                stateSave: true
            });

        },
        error: function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code loads the data in my Jquery Datatable called "submitted_rewards" correctly. The page size of the table is set to '10' as a default (10 rows per page). Now, I tried to go to the second page and click on the row to redirect to another page OR if I tried to click on the delete button to delete a row and it did not work! Those events work only for the page that a user lands on the first time. I am saving the state of the table that mean if I switched from page 1 to page 2 then refreshed that page. The events of each row in page 2 ONLY will work.

I tried to use the event initComplete but it did not work. Any idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you attach handlers to DOM elements and those DOM elements are destroyed your handlers will be of no effect anymore and the related code will be garbage collected at some point.

When you change pages by doing `window.location.href = ...`, you are effectively replacing your DOM elements (and script) with a new set from the page that is replacing it. Consequently, your handlers will no longer apply.

You can address this in a couple ways.

1) You will need to add script to each page you are loading and have it execute when the DOM is ready, applying handlers to the DOM elements on that page.

2) Do another ajax request to get new data and replace certain elements on your page. Use jQuery's .delegate() to attach handlers automatically to certain elements even as you add them later.

Comment: That is absolutely true.. This code that I have right now is inside document ready event. See my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working because I am appending every 10 rows to the table.. I appended all the rows of the table at one shot and then have the clicking events then it is going to work. 
If I want to keep loading every 10 rows. then I have to move the events inside the if statement like the following:

```
if (i % 10 == 0 || i == rewards.length - 1) {
   $("#submitted_rewards > tbody").append(tr);
   tr = "";
   $("#submitted_rewards tbody tr td:not(:last-child)").on("click", function () {
         var r_id = $(this).parent().attr("r_id");
         window.location.href = "./reward-info.aspx?id=" + r_id;
   });

   $(".delete").click(function () {
        var r = $(this).attr("r_id");
        $("tr[r_id=" + r + "]").fadeOut();
   });
}
```